# Dropdown Menu hidden under Footer

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

There are 100s of product categories on this website. As per requirement, I have to list most of them in the header as a dropdown menu. On the large pages, there is no issue as all of the menu items are visible. But on small pages e.g. [Contact Page](http://digitalstore.pk/contact.html), large submenu items are hidden behind the footer. Same can be seen in the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot - Large dropdown menu hidden behind footer]

I have already tried high z-index value (z-index: 1000000;) but still unable to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if the parent element has overflow:hidden property. Then z-index has no effect. Try removing overflow property from your parent element.